# Listview remove item border and checkmark

Tags: css, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm sorry if answer on this question is to easy, but I was realy trying to find answer on the internet, but without any success.

I wish to remove all kind of borders and checkmark's from my listview. How can I do this?

I already tryed to set border and outline on none or transparent or something, but there is still some kind of gray border. I have no idea how can I remove this one or how to remove checkmark?

My current result is this(when item has .win-selected class):

[image]

Html code:

```
<div class="filterPanel left">
     <h2 class="title">Status filter</h2>
     <div id="labRole_name" class="filter-view win-selectionstylefilled" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"  data-win-options="{ selectionMode: 'single', tapBehavior: 'directSelect',  layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout } }"></div>
</div>
```

And css code:

```
.filter-view {
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    color: gray;
}

    .filter-view .item {
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
        outline: #F2F2F2 solid 10px;
    }

    .filter-view .item *{
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .filter-view .win-selected .item:hover .count,
    .filter-view .item:hover .count {
        color: #4BB3DD !important;
    }

    .filter-view .win-selected .item:hover .filter,
    .filter-view .item:hover .filter {
        color: #8B8B8B !important;
    }

    .filter-view .win-selected .item .filter,
    .filter-view .item .filter {
        color: #333333 !important;
    }

    .filter-view .win-selected .item .count,
    .filter-view .item .count {
        color: #0096D1 !important;
    }

    .filter-view .item .filter {
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 160px;
        height: 20px;
        white-space: nowrap; 
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .filter-view .item .count{
        min-width: 30px;
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
```

Comment: please post HTML code

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this outline:

```
.filter-view .item {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    outline: #F2F2F2 solid 10px;
}
```

Should be

```
.filter-view .item {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    outline: 0;
}
```

And if is possible post a link of your page online.

Comment: Still the same...i add outline just because I wish to cover gray border. I add this color, because I use the same for app background(#F2F2F2).

Comment: Yes I did, but it seams, that it does not affect on the that border.
When I add new outline, it looks like the new outline is above the old one, so it only cover's that gray border...

Comment: You have a link so I can watch the page ?

Comment: actually this is metro app...an windows store app, so there is no link, otherwise It will be added already :)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1geu41qlyfoudow/App7.zip

here is this example...only listview with css...

Answer (score 0):

To make items not selectable, selectionMode for the listview needs to be set. you may also want swipeBehavior and tapBehavior to be none.

```
<div id="listView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" 
  data-win-options="{ 
       selectionMode: 'none', swipeBehavior: 'none', 
       tapBehavior: 'none' }">
</div>
```

Regards the mouse hover highlight - [styling listview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211837.aspx) topic might help.

Comment: Yes, but I need selectionMode to be set on "single".
Also, I need selection, but I wish to remove this ugly border :) that's it :D I thought that the removal of border or outline will do the trick, but apparently I was wrong :/

Comment: refer the css classes e.g. `win-selectioncheckmark` in the styling listview link in answer. using them in your css to style listview. for details - you can search these css classes in winjslib/css/ui-light.css file. hth.

Comment: ok, I try to edit every win-selectioncheckmark in my css code using: border-color: transparent !important;

but still the same...

Answer (score 0):

To change the border appearance of ListView's item hover and active state, you'll have to override `.win-itembox`'s value with **::before** selector.

```
.win-listview .win-itembox:hover::before {
    border-color: transparent; /* get rid of border, both of :hover and .win-pressed (same as :active) */
}
```

The default values can be found at ui-light.css or ui-dark.css, where the opacity and the color value of border is located.

```
/* the default value of WinJS ListView's item hover and active color from ui-light.css */
html.win-hoverable .win-listview .win-itembox:hover::before,
html.win-hoverable .win-itemcontainer .win-itembox:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
html.win-hoverable .win-listview .win-pressed .win-itembox:hover::before,
html.win-hoverable .win-listview .win-pressed.win-itembox:hover::before,
html.win-hoverable .win-itemcontainer.win-pressed .win-itembox:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

...

html.win-hoverable .win-listview .win-itembox:hover::before,
html.win-hoverable .win-itemcontainer .win-itembox:hover::before {
  border-color: #000000;
}
```